# Place 3 tables top left side, 2nd one below it (left side) and 3rd one on the top right

Tags: html, css, vertical-alignment, css-tables

How do I place 3 tables L1, L2, R1 in the specified below position:

1. L1 on Top Left
2. L2 below L1 on the Left
3. R1 on the Top Right

```
table.one {
float:left;
width:45%;
}

table.two   {
width:45%;
float:right;
}
```

https://jsfiddle.net/Lvsu0vdz/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No bootstrap required. Here you go.

```css
 .inlineTable {
   display: inline-block;
 }
 table.one {
   width: 45%;
   display: inline-block;
 }
 table.two {
   width: 45% float: left;
 }
```

```html
<div class="inline table">
  <table class="one">
    <tr>
      <th>Month-1</th>
      <th>Savings-1</th>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td>January</td>
      <td>$100</td>
    </tr>
  </table>

  <table class="one">
    <tr>
      <th>Month-2</th>
      <th>Savings-2</th>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td>January</td>
      <td>$100</td>
    </tr>
  </table>
</div>

<table class="two">
  <tr>
    <th>Month-3</th>
    <th>Savings-3</th>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td>January</td>
    <td>$100</td>
  </tr>
</table>
```

Comment: it was a bit unclear which one u wanted on the top right, but you can fiddle with it. i didn't see any L1 of L2 marked!

Comment: Thanks. This works partially.  As I aksed:                                                            "How do i place 3 tables L1, L2, R1 in the specified below position: 1) L1 on Top Left 2) L2 below L1 on the Left 3) R1 on the Top Right"                        So, when I increase the number of rows of the table R1, the L2 table doesn't come right below L1, there is a lot of gap between L1 and L2 as we used inline. Here is the code snippet i tried which creates the misalignment:  https://jsfiddle.net/tyv8tc7h/                                                    Can L1 start at top left?

Comment: @user3921458 can you clarify? i can fix it

Comment: If I add multiple rows to table on the right, the table on the left keeps scrolling down, can you please check this snippet? : https://jsfiddle.net/cyppyntp/1/                                                                                 In my case all 3 tables have  different content and different sizes in terms of rows.

Comment: @user3921458 pls accept my answer i put quite a bit of effort in

Comment: Sure, this aligns it to the Top Left. But the table below just keeps going way down, is there no way i can make it sit right below this top left table? I have my right table of 8 rows - the bottom left table is way down below then. Thanks again for your help.

Comment: it aligns it so the tables go to the top instead of sailing down. you can add as much content as you like, but you can only have 2 divs on one row